# Remove double parenthesis from subfigure caption

Tags: floats, captions, parentheses, subfig

I am using subfigure in a memoir environment. I would like to know how to remove the double parenthesis from the caption of the subfigures:
[image]

Here the code I am using (MWE):

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.32\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{./figures/rig1.png}
\caption{}
  \label{fig:rigid1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.32\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{./figures/rig1.png}
\caption{}
  \label{fig:rigid2}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.32\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{./figures/rig3.png}
\caption{}
  \label{fig:rigid3}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{
Global rigidity:~\cref{fig:rigid1} is ...\cref{fig:rigid2}
}
\label{fig:global}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, is `\thesubfigure` defined as `(\alph{subfigure})`? Hard to see without a compilable document

Comment: You can use \meaning\thesubfigure to get the current definition (more or less).